# Yii2 API Rest query parameters or condition

Tags: rest, yii2

I'm developing an API REST application with Yii2 and I have this query problem:

I receive a **get request by url with two params** like this:

```
http://localhost/yii2/rest/web/index.php/v1/functions/search?name=test&code=int
```

I would like to treat the get params with an **Or condition** in my SQL query, instead of an And condition.

I know that using **this way it works**:

```
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $model->find()->select('idFunction')->where(['or',['name'=>'test'],['code'=>'int']]),
    'pagination' => false
]);
```

But **this way doesn't work**. It behaves as an And condition:

```
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $model->find()->select('idFunction')->where(['or',$params]),
    'pagination' => false
]);
```

I think it has to do the way the variable `$params` is converted.

Here is my entire code:

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $params = \Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    exit(print_r($params));
    if (!empty($params)) {
        $model = new $this->modelClass;
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (!$model->hasAttribute($key)) {
                throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Invalid attribute:' . $key);
            }
        }
        try {
            $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $model->find()->select('idFunction')->where(['or',$params]),

                'pagination' => false
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(500, 'Internal server error');
        }

        if ($provider->getCount() <= 0) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'No entries found with this query string');
        } else {
            return $provider;
        }
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400, 'There are no query string');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that you are passing all the parameters in an array as the second element of the array that has the `or`, basically doing `allThis` `or` `null` so it works as an `and`. Did you try making the first element an `or`? Something like this: `$model->find()->where(array_unshift($params, 'or'))`? You could give that a try and check the generated SQL on the debugger.

Comment: Tks for your response @RaulSauco. I've tried your recommendation and now it brings me all ids values from the table. How could check the generated SQL on the debugger?

Comment: If you have the debugger configured, YII_DEBUG is true, and your IP is on the allowed list, i.e. you are on the same machine as the server, you should be seing the debug bar at the bottom of the page. You can also access the page at the http://localhost/mypage/debug endpoint.

Comment: They probably won't see the debug bar when testing REST requests. But, there should be link to debugger page for specific request in response headers.

Comment: @RaulSauco thanks! I've reached the debuger page, but, as Michal Hynčica said, I couldn't go further than a requests status list. I guess is because i'm trying testing request REST

Comment: @MichalHynčica you are right, I didn't realize before that the question was about a REST request, no debug bar. In any case, I normally access both backends and APIs debug logs through a separate tab, just to get the extra space, that would still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can iterate over the parameter array to modify it.

Using `array_unshift($conditions, 'or')` like I suggested on the comments **does not work**. The method expects an array where each element, except the operand itself, is itself, an array with only one element.

[Yii2 operator format docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#operator-format)

Something that works, I just tried, but it isn't very pretty, is to iterate over the elements and return an array of the expected form.

```php
$orQuery = ['or'];
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
   $orQuery[] = [$key => $value];
}
$query->where($orQuery);
```

This returns the array that the `query()` method expects.

```php
['or', ['name1' => 'value1'], ['name2' => 'value2'], ...]
```

That produces the SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ('name1'='value1') OR ('name2'='value2')...;
```

Comment: @4aLifeTime Great to hear that it worked. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and/or vote it up.

Comment: Yes, I just did it. As i'm new at stackoverflow i can't vote yet and after your comment i've realized i can mark answers as accepted, so i did it. Thanks again!